# I2C Addresses - How to check

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, i2c, addressing

I want to use these two devices - [24AA512](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/24AA512-24LC512-24FC512-512K-Bit-I2C-Serial-EEPROM-20001754Q.pdf) and [MCP79410M](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20002266h.pdf). The EEPROM part has external A0, A1 & A2 for address. But the other part does not have external address pins. In this case, how to configure the address for the MCP part?

Whether can I use the same I2C bus for these 2 peripherals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. how to configure the address for the MCP part?

You can't configure the address. From section 4.1.2 of the linked MCP datasheet:

> The next three bits are non-configurable Chip Select bits that must
> always be set to ‘1’.

2. can I use the same I2C bus for these 2 peripherals?

Yes, just as long you don't set A0, A1 and A2 all to 1. You should be looking at the "bus timing data" of both datasheet to verify they match specifications, and the "control byte format" to verify they don't collide.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a couple of follow-up questions.

Comment: 1. I see that the EEPROM IC has external pins for the address. Whereas, the MCP device, does not have external pins for address. So, some I2C devices, have external pins for address. If the I2C device doesn't have external pins for address, I need to check in the addressing section where the address will be taken care in the firmware, is it? 2. Could you tell me why should I verify the bus timing data and the control byte format for both the devices? These devices should follow the I2C standard right? The timing data should be the same right? And should the control byte format be different?

Comment: Also, in the MCP datasheet, figure 4-3 on page 10, there are 2 control byte formats, right? Why there are 2 formats and which one should I refer?

Comment: @Freshman **1.** Correct. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14I98.png) for comparison. I2C devices having external address pins allow multiple chips to be used in parallel. For 24AA512, 8 of them can be used on the same line (000 to 111). **2.** Although different devices are I2C compliant, it's still good to check timings just to make sure they can operate at the same frequency (e.g. 400 kHz) as the same master will be used for all of them. **3.** Read the datasheet again. One is for EEPROM read/write operations whilst the other is for SRAM/Real-Time-Clock-Calendar read/write operations.

Answer (score 3):

Yes these chips can exist on same bus just fine, as long as the EEPROM chip is set to an address that does not overlap the fixed RTC EEPROM address.

> RTCC : 1101111b
>
> RTCE : 1010111b
>
> EEPR : 1010XXXb where XXX are the 3 address pins.`

So the EEPROM can be set to any of the 7 addresses from the 8 that are available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A couple of follow-up questions. 1. What is the RTCC and RTCE addresses in your answer that you mentioned? I understand RTCC and RTCE have the same address. But why there are two? 2.  I see that the EEPROM IC has external pins for the address. Whereas, the MCP device, does not have external pins for address. So, some I2C devices, have external pins for address. If the I2C device doesn't have external pins for address, I need to check in the addressing section where the address will be taken care in the firmware, is it?

Comment: The RTC chip has two addresses. They are not the same address, look at the bit patterns, they are different. One for the RTC and one for the EEPROM. You can't change them as it has no external address setting pins and must use these addresses. You always need to check datasheets for what addresses each chip uses and if they are selectable or not.